# Browser says access-control-allow-origin header not present in clojure ring

Tags: http, clojure, cors, clojure-ring

I make a request to a server through the client browser like so https://example.com/bar, but get the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/bar/' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

However, when using clj-http.client, I get the following headers:

```
{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Content-Type",
  "Server" "Aleph/0.4.4",
  "Via" "1.1 vegur",
  "Content-Type" "application/edn",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*",
  "Connection" "close",
  "Transfer-Encoding" "chunked",
  "Access-Control-Request-Method" "GET",
  "Date" "Sat, 14 Mar 2020 10:10:43 GMT",
  "Vary" "Accept-Encoding"},
```

If the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present in the header through the clj-http.client request, then why does the browser say it isn't?

--- EDIT ---

What works:

```
;; clj-http.client gives the correct response with the headers above. 
(get "https://www.example.com/bar")
```

gives:

```
{:cached nil,
 :request-time 456,
 :repeatable? false,
 :protocol-version {:name "HTTP", :major 1, :minor 1},
 :streaming? true,
 :http-client
 #object[org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient 0x367237a0 "org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient@367237a0"],
 :chunked? true,
 :reason-phrase "OK",
 :headers
 {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Content-Type",
  "Server" "Aleph/0.4.4",
  "Via" "1.1 vegur",
  "Content-Type" "application/edn",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*",
  "Connection" "close",
  "Transfer-Encoding" "chunked",
  "Access-Control-Request-Method" "GET",
  "Date" "Sat, 14 Mar 2020 18:54:05 GMT",
  "Vary" "Accept-Encoding"},
 :orig-content-encoding nil,
 :status 200,
 :length -1,
 :body
 "({:foo \"bar\", :foo2 \"bar2\", :foo4 0, :foo3 [\"...
 :trace-redirects []
}
```

What doesn't work

```
;; At the client, using cljs-http.client
   (go (let [response (<! (http/get https://example.com/bar))]  
        (prn response)))
```

prints

```
{:status 0, :success false, :body "", :headers {}, :trace-redirects ["https://example.com/bar" "https://example.com/bar"], :error-code :http-error, :error-text " [0]"}
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: status is 200 as expected.

Comment: we need the full request and response here

Comment: CORS is a very tricky topic especially with Chrome. Also, if the request you are making is not a "simple request" - a preflight call will be made that needs to be handled correctly.

Comment: also, if you are sending credentials (like a cookie or an Authorization header), you can't use 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' set to "*".

Comment: all the messy details are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: full response in the updated edit.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer, the problem boils down to using clj-http client and cljs-http.client. It works when I use clj-http (even when the request server isn't the same as the response server) but doesn't when I use cljs-http. In the former case I get status 200, and in the latter status 0.

Comment: Why would the cljs-http.client request be blocked by the cors policy if the clj-http.client request isn't?

Comment: because if you are running in a browser, all actual HTTP requests are done and controlled by the browser. It doesn't matter if you are using `fetch` or `cljs-http` or `XMLHttpRequest`. 
The security mechanism in the browser will enforce CORS (see link above)